# How to not repeat recycle view inside nested layout?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to create a nested recycle view. So far i have a parent recycle view and under this i have a child recycle view. The problem that i am having is my child recycle view continues to be recycled with my parent recycle view. I do not want this i would like the child recycle view to only be recycled once. Does any one know how to go about fixing this. I understand this might sound a little confusing, but an example of what i want is instagram news feed. The top of the app have circle image views with your followers stories which can be swiped and the bottom have the news feed itself, in my case my app loads the user stories continuously under the news feed as i continue to scroll users stories are being continuously recycled under the news feed post.

**Main UI with parent recycleView**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">


    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/newsFeedToolBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backButton"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp"
            android:onClick="backImageView"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="15dp" />


    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        android:queryHint="Search"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/newsFeedToolBar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/newsFeedToolBar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/newsFeedToolBar"
        app:searchIcon="@null" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/newsRecycleVIew"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/News"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/News"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="News"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.045"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/searchView" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


*Row Item for parent recycleview added child recycle view*


 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/constraintlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="15dp">


        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView

            android:id="@+id/cardView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:cardElevation="5dp"

            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/newsThumbNail"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.448"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/newsTitle"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Dangerous fire is out of control at 24 and park"
                    android:textSize="17sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/newsThumbNail"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/newsThumbNail"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/newsThumbNail" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/newsBody"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="Some text is here"


                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/newsTitle"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/newsTitle"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/newsTitle" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/earningsRecycleView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.448"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:text="Upcoming Earnings"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.045"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardView" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Parent RecycleView adapter **

```
public class SearchStockAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SearchStockAdapter.SearchStocksViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<News_Model> stockInformaiton;

    private RequestQueue requestQueue;


    private SearchStockSubAdapter searchStockSubAdapter;


    private RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool viewPool = new RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool();


    public SearchStockAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<News_Model> stockInformaiton) {
        this.context = context;
        this.stockInformaiton = stockInformaiton;


    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public SearchStocksViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.search_stock_row, viewGroup, false);
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

        return new SearchStocksViewHolder(view);

    }


    //Loads data into views
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SearchStocksViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {


        viewHolder.newsTitle.setText(stockInformaiton.get(i).getTitle());
        viewHolder.newsBody.setText(stockInformaiton.get(i).getDescription());
        Glide.with(this.context).asBitmap().load(stockInformaiton.get(i).getUrlToImage()).into(viewHolder.newsThumbImage);


        //Second recycle view...
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(
                viewHolder.upcomingEarningsRecycleView.getContext(),
                LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,
                false
        );
        layoutManager.setInitialPrefetchItemCount(stockInformaiton.size());


        //second recycle view..
        SearchStockSubAdapter stockSubAdapter = new SearchStockSubAdapter(context, stockInformaiton);
        viewHolder.upcomingEarningsRecycleView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        viewHolder.upcomingEarningsRecycleView.setAdapter(stockSubAdapter);
        viewHolder.upcomingEarningsRecycleView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        viewHolder.upcomingEarningsRecycleView.setRecycledViewPool(viewPool);


    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return stockInformaiton.size();

    }

    static class SearchStocksViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView newsTitle, newsBody;
        private ImageView newsThumbImage;

        private RecyclerView upcomingEarningsRecycleView;


        public SearchStocksViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            //newsThumbnail = itemView.findViewById(R.id.newsThumbNail);
            newsTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.newsTitle);
            newsBody = itemView.findViewById(R.id.newsBody);
            newsThumbImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.newsThumbNail);
            upcomingEarningsRecycleView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.earningsRecycleView);


        }


    }


}
```

Comment: "Meaning if the user scrolls past it, then it just shows the main recycleview" Not sure what you want. If you describe clearly maybe others can help you. You should attach screenshot current and your expectation.

Comment: Man i don't even know how to formulae this question. I been thinking about it for days. I just wanna be able to create a nested layout.